# Customizing product slider, WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

Iam somewhat of a newbie when it comes to wordpress. so bear with me.
ive been trying to make a simple slider that will display 3 catagories. 
- books
- Boardgames
- office supplies

iam making it for someone who dosnt want a web store but just wanting it to display items in a meaningfull and dynamik way.

what ive tried is installing the WooCommerce plugin to make all my products and then installing the product slider by pickplugins.

I like the way it looks and i want to make two more. but i see no option to choose between different catagories in the slider options, so if i make 2 more sliders it will just display the same items (all of them).

the site is: http://nordborgboghandel.dk/

and the slider i want is something like there is on the frontpage.

anybody fixed a similar problem??

-Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I was once stuck into a same situation, in which we had to customize the slider. Basically you will have to play with the CSS and JS of the slider plugin which you have used to create the slider.

You can start of by having a look at the js and the css used by the slider. Refer the documentation of the slider if available, I am sure if they have any documentation you can have it customized easily by modifying some values in it. If not then you will have to check the JS code and try to hack it yourself to fit your needs.

Comment: I just checked your carousel on the homepage, and you are using the owl carousel. You can refer the documentation for modifying the carousel. Check this link : http://www.owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/demos/manipulations.html

Comment: Hey man, 
Thank you for the answer! i will look into it!
with all of the cool things and easy setup in generel using wordpress, i think its somewhat wierd that this somewhat normal feature isnt in any of them! :-)

Comment: do you know when using owl carousel, where do i find the "url" to paste in when making the carousel? :)

Comment: URL ? You mean the target href for the list items ?

Comment: Please check the demo link for the Owl carousel. http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/demos/images.html . Frankly speaking, I haven't used this plugin till now.